# How to add bar value to the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R code which generate a graph of the number of alerts per week. The graph looks great, but I'd like to add the exact value of the bar. I've been trying to do this using geom_text, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't know about the variable ..count.. and I don't know how to refer to the value of the bar otherwise.

```
a = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
sa2 = data.frame(WeekOfYear = a, UrgentState = b, IsUrgent = b)

p <- qplot(factor(WeekOfYear), data=sa2, geom="bar", fill=factor(UrgentState), order=-as.numeric(IsUrgent))
p <- p + geom_bar()
# p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = factor(WeekOfYear), y = ..count..)) THIS DOESN'T WORK
p <- p + ggtitle("Number of alerts per week")
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name="Week")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(name="Number of alerts")
```

Is there a way to add the value for all the values within the bar (fill)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p + stat_bin(aes(fill=NA,label=..count..),
            geom="text",vjust=-1)
```

Just leave out `fill=NA` if you don't want the numbers for the total bars.

Comment: Thank you Roland! It works great! However, I am getting the following warning and I am not sure how to get rid of it: "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead".

Comment: The warning is harmless. You could avoid it by defining `ymax=..count..`.